# Reactjs: How to create a audio volume meter

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, audio-streaming

I need some suggestion to create a volume meter bar . I am using reactjs with material ui. I have a basic implmentation with **LinearProgress**. Now I want to upgrade this one with a new design. How can we do this with **Material-ui**. Any suggestion would be helpful for me for a right direction.

**basic code**

```
class AudioProgress extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
        <LinearProgress variant="determinate" value={10} className="audio-meter"/>
     );
  }
}

export default  withStyles(styles)(AudioProgress);
```

**UPDATE**
Added html to started with progress bar. Now i want suggestion how can I update/chaneg accordingly for html update with color.
Any further suggestion please.

**starter code**

```
render() {
    const value = 20;
    return (

          <div class="container">
            <div class="progress-segment">
              <div class="item "></div>
              <div class="item "></div>
              <div class="item "></div>
              <div class="item "></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item "></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item "></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>
              <div class="item"></div>

            </div>
          </div>
          
     );
  }
```

**design**
[image]

**New Design**
[image]

Comment: Customize a [Rating](https://material-ui.com/components/rating/) component? Are you being required to use Material-UI for this design? Seems you ought to be able to accomplish with with a set of styled divs and some logic.

Comment: @DrewReese I have updated the html how can I now update accordingly for html.

Comment: Not sure what you are requesting now.

Comment: I am planning to create it from scratch. So just need some idea how can i change and update the color for each div accordingly with respect to value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really fluent in react but this should point you into the right direction. If this isn't the "react way" to do it, I'm open to any suggestions.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vg2j4b?file=src/App.js

The basic idea is that you have a certain amount of divs representing the bars. Each bar is colored gray at the beginning. When you have a volume (example 80 = 80% Volume) you iterate over each bar and check if the current iteration i is bigger than the volume divided by (100 / amount of bars). In my example this is 100 / 5 = 20 because there are 5 bars. If the condition is true add another class which colors the divs green. If you got any questions feel free to ask them.

Comment: In React we generally **do not** directly manipulate the DOM (`getElementsByClassName` and mutating the class list, etc...) but the basic concept is close to this.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use one of Material UI's premium themes. Pretty sure some of them have what you are looking for. You can find them [here](https://material-ui.com/store/).

Comment: thanks for your sugegstion. But need to explore with these html and some react.So may be this won't fit in my case.Thanks though.